# Highchart position changes when I open console or resize browser

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts

I have setup highchart in my vue.js template. I noticed that when i open the browser console or resize the browser, the highchart tends to move up. But right after refreshing the page with that browser size, it aligns perfectly in the centre.

[image]

Here is my code

```
<template>
 <highcharts :options="chartOptions"></highcharts>
</template>

 <script>
 import { Chart } from "highcharts-vue";

 export default {
  name: "CustomGuage",
  components: {
   highcharts: Chart
 },
 props: ["data", "title", "name", "min", "max", "format", "text", "x", "y", "target", 
 "targetFormat"],
  data() {
    return {
      chartOptions: {
       chart: {
      type: "solidgauge",
       style: {
        fontFamily: 'Segoe UI Light',
        fontSize :'22px',
    },

      //   plotBackgroundColor: null,
      //   plotBackgroundImage: null,
      //   plotBorderWidth: 0,
      //   plotShadow: false,

      marginBottom: 190
    },

    title: {
      text: this.title,
      align: "left"
    },

    pane: {
      center: ["50%", "85%"],
      startAngle: -90,
      endAngle: 90,
      size: 200,
      background: {
        innerRadius: "60%",
        outerRadius: "100%",
        shape: "arc",
        backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2'
      }
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
    
      min: 0,
      max: this.max,
      stops: [
        [0.1, "#c00000"], // green
        [0.5, "#ffc000"], // yellow
        [0.9, "#4f6228"] // red
      ],
      //  minColor: '#DF5353',
      //   maxColor: '#55BF3B',
      lineWidth: 0,
      //tickWidth: 0,
      minorTickInterval: null,
      tickPositions: [0, this.max], 
      title: {
        y: -70
      },
      labels: {
        y: 16
      }
    },

    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
      solidgauge: {
        dataLabels: {
          y: -1,
          borderWidth: 0,
          useHTML: true,
          
        }
      }
    },

    series: [
      {
        name: this.name,
        data: this.data,
        dataLabels: {
          format: this.format
        
        },
        
        
      },
      {
        data: this.target,
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          format:this.targetFormat,
           verticalAlign: 'top',
          borderWidth: 0,
          //useHTML: true,
        },
        tooltip: {
          enabled: false
        },
        type: "gauge",
        dial: {
          baseLength: "100%",
          radius: "110%",
          rearLength: "-45%", 
           
          
        },
      }
     ]
    }
  };
  },

 }
};
</script>
```

Is there anything i can add or do to make sure that the chart position does not change?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this behaviour on some online editor which I could work on? I reproduced your Highcharts config and it seems that something different must have an impact on it. https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-demo-22d29

Comment: i noticed that when i set the height of the container the chart is in, that is when the chart tends to move , ur solution gave me the idea to look elsewhere for the problem, Thanks